# Rails gem for transliterate + highlight

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I just implemented a search page in Ruby on Rails, and found a couple of super useful Rails methods: [excerpt](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/TextHelper.html#method-i-excerpt), and [highlight](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/TextHelper.html#method-i-highlight).

Highlight is pretty darn useful when displaying search results:

```
> bin/rails console
Loading development environment (Rails 4.2.1)
irb(main):001:0> include ActionView::Helpers::TextHelper
=> Object
irb(main):003:0> highlight "Dusseldorf Open 2015", "duss"
=> "<mark>Duss</mark>eldorf Open 2015"
```

but it lacks support for transliteration:

```
irb(main):002:0> highlight "Düsseldorf Open 2015", "duss"
=> "Düsseldorf Open 2015"
```

No marking =(.

One workaround is to call transliterate before [highlight](https://github.com/jfly/worldcubeassociation.org/blob/85dbbeae67287b16a1af653feb7062f4a32aae7d/WcaOnRails/app/helpers/application_helper.rb#L41-L54), but that means the final text is missing the umlaut:

```
irb(main):008:0> include ActiveSupport::Inflector
irb(main):008:0> transliterate "Düsseldorf Open 2015"
=> "Dusseldorf Open 2015"
irb(main):009:0> highlight transliterate("Düsseldorf Open 2015"), "duss"
=> "<mark>Duss</mark>eldorf Open 2015"
```

and this looks particularly bad for text with characters that transliterate just gives up on:

```
irb(main):011:0> highlight transliterate("Yu Nakajima (中島悠)"), "yu"
=> "<mark>Yu</mark> Nakajima (???)"
```

You can see all of this in pretty screenshots over on our [github issue](https://github.com/cubing/worldcubeassociation.org/issues/238), all of which applies to [Rails's excerpt method](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/TextHelper.html#method-i-excerpt) as well.

I tried searching for [highlight](https://rubygems.org/search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&query=highlight) and [excerpt](https://rubygems.org/search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&query=excerpt) on rubygems, to no avail. Searching for "highlight" just comes up with tons of code highlighting solutions. Am I failing to find a community solution to this problem, or does one just not exist?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After not finding any solutions to this issue, I decided to create my own gem called [`translighterate`](https://github.com/jfly/translighterate) that handles the highlight aspect of this.

For excerpt, we ended up implementing that ourselves (although it might make sense to put this code into my aforementioned `translighterate` gem). You can see that code [here](https://github.com/thewca/worldcubeassociation.org/blob/7baecc2c19cc42c63e9b3ad76187e5987a491bad/WcaOnRails/app/helpers/application_helper.rb#L56-L72).